# Is there a reason for substituting NULLs with empty string in SSRS reports?

Tags: sql, oracle, reporting-services

In some of the reports I see (with oracle data source) the NULLs in columns are substituted with spaces or empty strings:

```
NVL(col, ' ') AS col
NVL(col2, '') AS col2
```

Is there a reason for that? Does SSRS handle this data in some other way than the regular nulls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If an expression/function inside the report was manipulating the data it would have have to constantly check if the value is `NULL`.

For instance:

```
 IIF(IsNothing(Fields!col1.Value),"Field is NULL",Fields!col1.Value)
 IIF(IsNothing(Fields!col2.Value),"Field is NULL",Fields!col2.Value)
```

If the value is altered at the database level before being sent to the report it makes the code a little cleaner, i.e. you wouldn't have to check for `NULL` values and can reference the column directly.

```
 Fields!col2.Value
```

Comment: The are no manipulations whatsoever, the data is displayed exactly as it is returned from the dataset.

Comment: @kyooryu - then you're better off asking the dev who wrote (if possible).  That's the only valid reason I can think of.

Comment: Well, unfortunately the dev is long gone, that's why I asked here :)

Comment: @kyooryu - okay, the answer I provided is my best guess.